# Data Sharing Between Android Activities

Tags: android

I have a question that has been bugging me for a while now. I would like to know what is considered the canonical, or best practice, means of getting data from one activity to another. I am personally aware of two ways to do this. The first way is by bundling the data directly into the Intent via the putExtra() function (or something similar). However, this way seems to me to be a bit of a violation of encapsulation principles. The second way I have done this is by placing the data into a separate class, and sharing that class between the two activities. This seems to be more fundamentally sound, but I am still unsure. Anyone care to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same question when wrighting my app and I ended up creating my CustomApplication class that extends Application class and adding it to the  tag in my AndroidManifest.xml. This way I can store any types of data inside it with proper getters and setters. Calling (CustomApplication).getApplicationContext() will return CustomApplication object, which is unique for your whole app and exists in single instance(singleton) and using which you can set and get necessery values.

The benefit is that your Application object and data within it exists as long as any part of your app(Activities, Services, etc) is running.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to share data among `Activities`.

1. If the data is the pre-defined data type like `int`, `double`, `string`...just put it directly to `Intent`.
2. If data is in binary format or object-like, then implement the class into `Parcelable` interface, and put to `Intent` to send.
3. If the data is light or small, you do like 1, 2 above; however, if it's kind of big-enough to affect to performance or quality, then I think you need a data store. It's like to save data some where: like files, xml, database,... and read/write from it.

Answer (score 1):

Though you can implement any class into `Parcelable` interface to deliver them across activities, but this way will make a new copy of object and violate consistency.

Android is designed with Model–View–Controller (MVC). Activities are controllers, I think them should not keep data themselves nor deliver data directly. It would be a better practice that an Activity tell the next Activity where the data is, and the next Activity achieve the data from Model itself.

Maybe you can use `Provider`. Activity A put the data's uri into intent and send intent to start Activity B,  then Activity B get the data's uri from then intent and use it to achieve data from the Provider