# Android Java counter between activities

Tags: java, android

I am developing a game with two Activities. I have one class, `ModelGetter`, with this method:

```
public int getPoint {
    return point++;
}
```

When I press a button in FirstActivity I call `modelgetter.getPoint()` and it returns 0. When I press a button in SecondActivity I call `modelgetter1.getPoint()` again, and it still returns 0. I have created a new instance of `ModelGetter` in SecondActivity.

I don't know how to use the same instance in different activities and have my variable always increment.

Comment: please format your question so it becomes better readable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13079302/1689695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating an instance then the data will be diferent. If you want the same counter to be used change it to static. Create a class like this:

```
public class ModelGetter{

  public static int point;

  public static int getPoint(){
    return point++;
  }

}
```

And call it like `ModelGetter.getPoint();`

Comment: That's not what the op asked. So I'm sorry you inform you that this is not wrong whatsoever.

Comment: he is questioning why it returns 0 after he calls the method.. Read the question.

Comment: No. He is asking why the code is returning 0 the second time (`and it still returns 0`). Read it carefully next time before judging other's answer. Also we are not here to compete with each other. Let the OP decide the best answer and stop critiquing others.

Comment: Using static in this way is not best practice. Rather use an  class for your shared data which can be accessed by both activities. Android follows MVC design

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using static/singleton's in android. This is not the best practice I agree with you since you can't guarantee the content of your static fields throughout the application life time, however it's still a simple and viable solution if the OP doesn't want to implement a serializable class and pass it though intents and whatnot.

Comment: Tanks at all developers.I have fix with static method an Variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to achieve what you want.

1. Make ModelGetter singleton.
2. Make getPoint and point static.

I have only two ideas for now.
I think there are other ways as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Application class to store the value. To get an Application instance from any activity you should call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()

To use a custom Application class you should create a class that inherites the

```
    android.app.Application
```

and then add a line to your manifest file:

```
 <application android:name="your.application.class"
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get 1 the first time you call it, the code should be:

```
    public static int getPoint {
       return ++point; // First increment the variable point and then return it.
    }
```

Declare the method itself as Static and call it using the class name **`ModelGetter.getPoint();`**

**Remember:** `return point ++` first returns and then increments the variable point. You don't want this.

In order to have access to the same variable from both activities declare it as class variable or "static"

```
  public static int point
```

Comment: both point variable and the getPoint method will have to be static, not just the variable

Comment: @Yosi199 Not if this method is in a superclass extended from both activities!

Comment: @Yosi199 so? You escaped?

Comment: lol what? r u kidding me. It's ok but you should have said that from the start thats all. I wasn't the one who voted down